# Check which indexes are needed in a data warehouse

Tags: mariadb, data-warehouse

I'm working on a data warehouse that is updated twice daily. Over the course of mart development and query optimization, a high number of indexes were defined. But also the reports have been changed and updated. Is there a way to find out which indexes are still required and which one could been dropped?

Answer (score 1):

First enable statistics with:

```
SET GLOBAL userstat = 1;
```

And run all the queries that are currently in use.

Then read the statistics with

```
SHOW INDEX_STATISTICS;
```

which will show the used indexes.

It might be needed to `FLUSH INDEX_STATISTICS` first to make sure to only see the indexes used.

See [the documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/user-statistics/) for more information.